# JSON Schema strict typing in PatternProperties

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have JSON document similar to below

```
{
  "dell": {
    "memory": {

      "RAM": {
        "RamType": "DDR",
        "Size": 16
      },
      "Graphic": {
        "RamType": "GDDR",
        "Size": 4,
        "dummy": "dummy"
      }
    },
    "dummy": "dummy"
  }
}
```

What I want is to have a list of key-value pairs where the key will be the name of computer and value would be properties of computers. Again in these values, I can have multiple key-value pairs as shown above.

And I have written JSON Schema with Draft 6 as below

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "computers": {
      "patternProperties": {
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "^[a-z0-9-_]+$": {
          "properties": {
            "memory": {
              "patternProperties": {
                "^[a-z0-9-_]+$": {
                  "additionalProperties": false,
                  "properties": {
                    "RamType": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "RamSize": {
                        "type": "number"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can try it out [here](https://jsonschemalint.com/#/version/draft-06/markup/json).

Problem is I don't want to allow user to enter "dummy" values as shown in the JSON given above. Clearly `"additionalProperties" : true` is not working. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that your schema describes a top level property called "computers" that your data doesn't have. Therefore, none of the data you were testing was being constrained at all by your schema. Another issue was that your regex doesn't match on uppercase characters.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "patternProperties": {
    "^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$": {
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "memory": {
          "patternProperties": {
            "^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$": {
              "additionalProperties": false,
              "properties": {
                "RamType": { "type": "string" },
                "Size": { "type": "number" }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. 
This works great. 

But if I add `"additionalProperties": "false"` after the `schema` element. It allows dummy element in the root element. What can I do to disallow this?

Comment: If you have `"additionalProperties": false` at the same level as `patternProperties`, it will only apply to properties that don't match `patternProperties`. "dummy" would match the pattern and would be allowed. "dummy!", however, would not match the pattern and `additionalProperties` should disallow it.

Comment: Apologies for the late response. The actual reason was my regex is different than yours. My regex was `^[a-z0-9-_]+$` it was not matching my keys. After updating it, it solved the issue.